# Union of closed balls centered with centers in a closed set is closed in Euclidean space

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}^n$ be the Euclidean space with the euclidean metric $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|_2$. Let $A$ be a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and for each $a\in A$, $D_a$ is a closed ball centered at $a$ such that the balls $D_a$ are pairwise disjoint. Is $\bigcup_{a\in A}D_a$ necessarily closed?

Note that $A$ is countable infinite or finite and that the hypothesis $A$ closed is needed because otherwise we take $\mathbb{R}$ and $A=\{1/n:n\in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$ and any balls $D_n$ will do.

Comment: Note this is equivalent to $\cap_{a\in A}\overline{D_a}$ being open.

Comment: @NickC Elaborate a little more, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the union is closed. Take any convergent sequence $(x_n)$ in $\bigcup_{a\in A} D_a$. If there is a ball $D_a$ containing infinitely many terms $x_n$, then it contains the limit $\lim x_n$. So, we may assume that each ball contains only finitely many terms. Pick a  subsequence $x_{n_k}$ such that the corresponding balls $D_{a_k}$ are distinct.

Suppose that there exists $r>0$ such that each ball $D_{a_k}$ has radius $\ge r$. Then for each $k$ there exists a ball $B_k$ of radius $r$ such that $x_{n_k}\in B_k\subset D_{a_k}$.  The union $\bigcup_k B_k$ is bounded, since the sequence $x_{n_k}$ is bounded. On the other hand, since $B_k$ are disjoint and have the same radius,  the set $\bigcup_k B_k$  has infinite measure: a contradiction.

(Alternative approach to the previous paragraph, without measure theory: let $Q$ be a cube containing $\bigcup_k B_k$. Subdivide it into equal cubes $Q_j$ of diameter less than $r$. Then for each $k$, there is a cube $Q_j$ contained in $B_k$: namely, any cube containing the center of $B_k$. But there are infinitely many balls $B_k$ and finitely many cubes $Q_j$, which yields a contradiction.)

Since the radii $D_{a_k}$ are not bounded from below by a positive constant, we may assume (after passing to a subsequence) that they converge to $0$. Hence, $|x_{n_k}-a_k|\to 0$, which implies 
$$
\lim x_{n_k} = \lim a_k \in A
$$
 proving the claim.

Comment: Sorry for not paying attention to the question before, but how do you get $r_k+r_j<|x_{n_k}-x_{n_j}|$? I do think the answer is overall good, though.

Comment: But then shouldn't it be $r_k+r_j<|a_k-a_j|$? where $a_k$ is the center of the ball $D_{a_k}$.

Comment: Good point. I changed the proof.

Comment: Very nice, I was thinking something similar. It'd be nice to have a proof without measure theory, though.

Comment: You can avoid measure theory by putting $\bigcup B_k$ in a cube and subdividing it into equal cubes that are small enough so that each $B_k$ contains at least one. I added this approach to the answer.